# How to handle events from web page with selenium in c#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have two tabs open(with same url) one is the parent other is the children. I make that if the parent change his url, children change it too.Everything is making with **Selenium C**#, But now i need to handle events. I need to handle click event on the web page and send it to some handler in the back-end. For example. if you have one input and one button and  if you write something in the input and click on button the action will be complete in the parent tab, but need to be complete in the children tabs too . Is it possible to do that with Selenium C# and if yes please help with some source code ? :).

Comment: Welcome to SO.Curious to know, why do you want to perform same operation on two tabs?

Comment: This is homework from my university. If i make i would not go to exam .